# Does a Saber-Toothed Tiger's Pounce grant it an immediate Bite attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, actions

The Saber-Toothed Tiger's Pounce feature is as follows:

> **Pounce.** If the tiger moves at least 20 feet straight toward a creature and then hits it with a claw attack on the same turn, that
>   target must succeed on a DC 14 Strength saving throw or be knocked
>   prone. *If the target is prone, the tiger can make one bite attack
>   against it as a bonus action*.

Based on the order in which the text is written, is it possible for the Tiger to move 20ft, make a claw attack (knocking the target prone), and then use its bonus action to bite its newly-prone victim?

Answer (score 13):

**Yes**, for two reasons:

1. The last sentence is part of the description of the Pounce ability, implying it's an elaboration of what happens if the target fails the saving throw from the initial attack. That's most of the point of the Pounce ability; it's intentionally worded differently from the Mastiff's attack ability.
2. Even if that weren't the case and the last sentence stood alone, the requirements are still met:

   > If [a] target is prone, the tiger can take a bonus action to make one bite attack against it.

   The target is prone, so you get a bonus attack.